# SQL: Join with complete participation

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have a table `Person(Name, Hobby)` and there are 3 hobbies in total. The table's values are like

```
Amy | Stamp Collection
Kevin | Mountain Biking
Kevin | Stamp Collection
Ron | Mountain Biking
```

Here, `Kevin` has both the hobbies `Mountain Biking` and `Stamp Collection`. I need to write a query to retrieve `Kevin`.

How can I get the **person who has all the hobbies**?

Thanks

Comment: As you can see from the answers, it's not clear what you are asking. Could you rephrase the question? You really want "the person who has all the hobbies", or all the hobbies for a particular person?

Comment: @bfavaretto I need "the person who has all the hobbies".. Rephrased.

Comment: Okay, so @Cade Roux gave you the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Hobby) FROM Person)
```

[Runnable example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62571/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9468844-sql-join-with-complete-participation)

Comment: that's what was asked for, but it is a funny question :)

Answer (score 1):

note : *not tested, and its correct in Oracle sql* 
you can try this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM
      (
       SELECT p.name,
              count(distinct p.hobby) cnt
         FROM Person p
        GROUP BY p.name
      ) p2
WHERE p2.cnt = (SELECT count(distinct  Hobby)
                  FROM Person)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the person's name and count use this:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, Name FROM Person group by Name limit 1
```

This will get you the person's name and the amount of hobbies they have. To get all hobbies add the field to the query and remove the grouping:

```
SELECT Name, Hobby FROM Person where Name = {name} limit 1
```

(without the curly braces)